# Re-set $TMUX after unsetting

Tags: tmux

I did the following to try and get Byobu to work (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099018/byobu-error-sessions-should-be-nested-with-care-unset-tmux-to-force ) on a Ubuntu server droplet I rent from Digital Ocean but it didn't fix my problem.

```
TMUX= ''
```

I would now like to revert it to it's original setting but do not know what the default should be. Is anyone able to advise?

I'm hoping I am correct in thinking this is the appropriate location to post this even though the original question I link to above is from the StackOverflow site.

Answer (score 3):

Logging in again should get you the value back in the new session.   If you did this in a sub-shell, exiting the sub-shell should reveal the original value.   You may be able to find the original value with `grep`.   Try the commands:

```
grep TMUX= ~/.??*
find /etc -type f | xargs grep TMUX=
```

Setting `$TMUX=''` may create an empty variable with the name specified by the `TMUX` variable.  The commands `TMUX=''` or `unset TMUX` will clear the `TMUX` variable.   The command  `echo TMUX=\"$TMUX\"` will echo a command you can use to restore the value to its current value.

When doing this kind of thing I recommend creating a backup variable like this:

```
TMUX_OLD="$TMUX"
$TMUX=''
```

You can then restore the value with the command:

```
TMUX="$TMUX_OLD"
```

EDIT: It may be possible to find the correct value in the environment of the parent process.  This may be readable using the command:

```
cat /proc/$PPID/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question, I did not use the dollar sign when entering the original command so I did in fact un-set the TMUX variable.

In which case, am I right in thinking I just need to enter the command returned from your "echo..." suggestion? Or can I just do TMUX=\"$TMUX\" without having to replace $TMUX with its actual value?

Comment: @drewstiff just open a new terminal, the command you ran should only have affected the shell you had opened.

Comment: If I end my session and re-start it and I try the command BYOBU I should get my original error of "ERROR: Sessions should be nested with care. Unset $TMUX to force" but instead it goes in to an unusable byobu session. This is how I know it has not reverted my changes to how they were before I started messing with things.

Comment: That last comment was in reply to @terdon sorry

Comment: @drewstiff - just include the user who you want to direct a comment to, like I did.

Comment: @drewstiff you can check the current value of `TMUX` by running `echo $TMUX`. In any case, the change you made should not affect any sessions other than the current one. If it still does not work, you have a different problem.

Comment: @terdon if I run `echo $TMUX` in a freshly-connected session it returns nothing. However if I start a tmux session from that new session, the same command gives me `/tmp/tmux-1000/default,20665,2` back. Should I set TMUX to this value from my 'base' session? Or have I royally titted things up?

Comment: @drewstiff I don't use `tmux` so I don't really know. However, it looks like `TMUX` is set only within a `tmux` session. I recommend posting a new question explaining your symptoms, what you describe is not related to your having manually set `TMUX`.